# Need help in using Regexp

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

```
SELECT value from table1 limit 3;
```

When I run the above query, I'm getting the below results:

```
;12770258;;;;103=::dupe::0|112=::dupe::0|114=search-results#product-id#Lettuce#not-recommended#r02#s01
;12880258;;;;103=::dupe::0|112=::dupe::0|114=search-results#product-id#Lettuce#not-recommended#r02#s01
;12990258;;;;103=::dupe::0|112=::dupe::0|114=search-results#product-id#Lettuce#not-recommended#r02#s01
```

I want the results to be displayed as below:

```
12770258
12880258
12990258
```

How to implement this using Regular Expression? Kindly guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` here:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '\\d+', 1, 1, 'i', 1) AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

The above call to `REGEXP_SUBSTR` finds the first digit in the column, starting the search at the start of the column.  In regex, `\d+` matches a group of one or more digit characters.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the answer you have provided?

Answer (score 1):

you could just use SPLIT if you know it's always the "second" value in the series. If that is not true, then the REGEPX version will not help you ether.

```
SELECT ';12770258;;;;103=::dupe::0|112=::dupe::0|114=search-results#product-id#Lettuce#not-recommended#r02#s01' as col1
    ,split(col1,';')[1]::text;
```

| COL1 | SPLIT(COL1,';')[1]::TEXT |
| --- | --- |
| ;12770258;;;;103=::dupe::0|112=::dupe::0|114=search-results#product-id#Lettuce#not-recommended#r02#s01 | 12770258 |